# Java Gui opening two windows

Tags: java, user-interface, window, gridbaglayout

Firstly, I'm new to Java GUIs so please bear with me.
I'me creating a pretty simple GUI from a Model-View-Controller setup, and all it does is display some labels, some textfields and some buttons; nothing fancy. I've got the GUI looking how I want with GridBagLayout, but the trouble I'm having is that whenever I call the GUI view class, I have two windows pop up, rather than one. The first window to open is the GridBagLayout with all my textfields and buttons, and the second is just a small window thing with only the minimise, maximise and close buttons (attached a photo).
[image: Annoying pop-up window]

My code is as follows (there are two other classes for model and controller)

```
public class classView extends JFrame {

   private classModel model;

   public classView(classModel model){
      this.model = model;
      JFrame mFrame = new JFrame("This is the view Frame");

      mFrame.setBounds(400, 400, 300, 300);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      addComponentsToPane(mFrame.getContentPane());
      mFrame.pack();
      mFrame.setVisible(true); 
      }

     private void addComponentsToPane(Container pane){
        // This is where I add the buttons and other fun stuff
     }
```

The classView is called like this in another class, along with classController and classModel.

```
public class classGUIBasics {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     classModel model = new classModel();
     classView view = new classView(model);
     new classController(model, view);
     view.setVisible(true);   
   }
}
```

I know it's probably something simple, but what am I doing wrong? How do I suppress this second window?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code your **classView** extends JFrame, so in fact classView is a JFrame, hence your view has all the properties of a JFrame.

So your code could be changed to:

```
class classView extends JFrame {

    private classModel model;

    public classView ( classModel model ) {
        this.model = model;

        this.setBounds( 400, 400, 300, 300 );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        addComponentsToPane();
        this.pack();
    }

    private void addComponentsToPane (  ) {
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        // This is where I add the buttons and other fun stuff
    }

}
```

And your **classGUIBasics** remains the same:

```
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    classModel model = new classModel();
    classView view = new classView( model );
    new classController( model, view );
    view.setVisible( true );
}
```

Additionally I would recommend to check the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Ahh perfect. Works like a charm. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

classView extends JFrame.And in the classView you create another JFrame ,mFrame.The visible of two JFrame is true.So you will see two window .Try to delete the code "view.setVisible(true);" in the classGUIBasics.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Is there anyway to do it from the classView side of things however? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is almost never a good reason for your class to extend JFrame. Your class should extend JPanel. then in the main() function you create a JFrame, create your class instance, add it to the frame, pack the frame and set it visible. this should also all be done on the Event thread, not the main thread:

```
public class MyClass extends JPanel {

   public MyClass() {
       // create the contents of the panel
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
      super.paintComponent( g );
      // other stuff here
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();
            jf.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void windowClosing( WindowEvent arg0 ) {
                  System.exit( 0 );
               }
            } );
            MyClass t = new MyClass();
            jf.add( t, BorderLayout.CENTER );
            jf.pack();
            jf.setVisible( true );
         }
      } );
   }
}
```

Note that this main method can be re-used for any of your applications, merely changing the one line that creates the MyClass instance.